# Flexbox: Container with two different directions

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make something like this:

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n83O.jpg)
- Wireframe

**Container** defines the screen size (100vw, 100vh) and **Box** put the content to center (horizontal and vertical alignment).

The two **Box** are by row, **Text** divs should be displayed by column. Is it possible with Flexbox?

**First solution**

HTML

```
.container{
list-style: none;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
display: flex;
height: 100vh;
}

.box{
width: 90vw;
height: 90vh;
display: flex;
}

.box li{
margin: 25px;
box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.image-1{
background-color: yellow;
height: 20vh;
width: 100%;
}

.image-2{
float: left;
background-color: dodgerblue;
height: 10vh;
width: 10vw;
}

.text{
background-color: orange;
height: 10vh;
width: 100%;
}
```

CSS

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <li style="flex-grow:1">
            <div class="image-1"></div>
            <div class="image-2"></div>
            <div class="text"></div>
        </li>
        <li style="flex-grow:1"></li>
    </div>
</div
```

**Second solution**

CSS

```
.container{
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
height: 100vh;
}

.container li{
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
margin: 5px;
height: 70vh;
width: 50vw;
}

.box{
margin-top: 15px;
height: 120px;
width: 100%;
background-color: orange;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <li>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </li>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Sure @Mistalis, just updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 90vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.box__half {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box__half:first-child {
  background: yellow;
}

.box__half:last-child {
  background: orange;
}

.text {
  width: 90%;
  height: 30vw;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 3% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box__half">
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box__half">
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="text"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, pretty close. What I can't do is to divide the vertical divs (**box_half**) into 2 **text** divs (where I can use _flex-grow_, maybe). I need to create something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEnMt.jpg

Answer (score 0):

the `li` should be displayed as flex too and the `flex-direction` of it should be column. It's just and nested flex.

Comment: I think the second is more reasonable, but if you follow my logic about nested flex displays, you will solve it anyway you want to.

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thanks!